# I need to click twice my button to open the sidebar menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Inside the sidebar, I replaced the  menu list with a user control to display the menu items.
The user control takes the menu items from my DB. Until then I was able to click only once on the toggle button to open the sidebar menu. After the change, I need to click twice to open the sidebar menu.

Before the change:

```
   <div id="pagecontainer" runat="server">
   <div id="SideBar">
    <div id="SideBarMenu"> 
 <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="../Invoices.aspx" class="active">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../dashboard.aspx">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">My Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../ProductListing.aspx">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-piggy-bank"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Products List</span>
                </a>
            </li>           
        </ul>
     </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

After the change:

```
    <div id="pagecontainer" runat="server">
    <div id="SideBar">
    <div id="SideBarMenu">             
    <uc:NewMenu id="dbMenu" runat="server" />               
    </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

the jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function SideBar_ShowHide()
      {
        var _sb = document.getElementById("SideBar");
        var _width = '12%';

        if(_sb.style.width == _width) {
            _sb.style.width = '0vw';
            return;
         }
           _sb.style.width = _width;
       };
     </script>
```

Comment: I guess it's because the first time you click `_sb.style.width == _width` is not true

Comment: I think it would be better to use a class to detect if the menu should be shown or not.

Comment: `if(_sb.style.width == _width) {` debug your code to see what these values *actually* are (obvious _width is defined line above), eg `console.log(_sb.style.width)` or step through the browser tools and inspect.

Comment: If you set breakpoint in `SideBar_ShowHide`,will you go to it when first clicking?I test with the js,it will go to `_sb.style.width = _width;` at the first time,and go to `_sb.style.width = '0vw';` at the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I need to click twice when the page loads the first time, once the sidebar has opened and close once the jquery show/hide works with one click only.
No error on debugging.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This comment would be more appropriately added to your Question, by editing it.